# Why does Python platform.architecture() return the Windows Pre-Install Environment?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, x86-64, platform

Seems like since Windows 10, the `platform.architecture()` function has been returning an erroneous value for the Windows Architecture. Shouldn't it identify AMD64? In any case PE is wrong.

[From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro?view=windows-11):

> Windows PE (WinPE) is a small operating system used to install, deploy, and repair Windows desktop editions, Windows Server, and other Windows operating systems.

When I start Python I get:

> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Then I execute the following Python commands with the shown result.

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Answer (score 3):

[`platform.architecture`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture) doesn't do what you think it does. It returns:

> the bit architecture and the linkage format ***used for the executable***.
> (emphasis mine)

i.e. the executable passed (`sys.executable`, your python installation, by default) is 64-bit and is a [Windows Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

If you want the machine type you want [`platform.machine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.machine):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'AMD64'
```